# How to add View or Label on Polyline using google maps in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, google-maps, google-polyline

I have achieved the Polyline (route path) using Google Map on my app, Further, I want to add a View or Label as shown in the below image.

[image]

**How to achieve the same in Swift?**

Comment: it is custom iconView, you can add it instead of marker icon

Comment: It seems that the last option, I will try it, Thank you

Comment: How to add this custom iconView with dynamic text label on the line, Im having this problem in Flutter